# Can one unset all parent classes when only a child class in known in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have extended a class that is part of a large library.

I instantiate the extended class.  Later, I'd like to unset() the extended class and all the related classes that have been instantiated in library.  How do I do this when I only know the extended class that I have instantiated.

Comment: PHP offers the possibility to unset things like private variables in class definitions but someone should not use it. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want to do. If you have **B** that has extended **A** then unsetting **A** will delete the data in the combined structure of **A** and **B**, Since **A extends B** basiclly ends up beeing a class made up of the code of **A** + **B**. But do you prehaps mean that you have some central object handler and whish to do some kind of reference counting?

Explain a bit further and prehaps paste some code and it will be more clear.

For your info, there is the function **get_parent_class()** that can be used to figure out what class a given class has extended.

But, if you just want to unset **B** and are afraid that the **A** portion of **B** would continue to live on you can relax. **Unset** unsets the **entire** object.